# Cannot boot Ubuntu after update from 18.04 to 18.10 (stuck at "Stopping User Manager for UID 121")

Tags: boot, 18.10

I tried to boot Ubuntu after an update from 18.04 to 18.10 an it is stuck on a black screen saying

```
Stopping User Manager for UID 121
/dev/sda4: clean, 685558/7798784 files, 12823603/31178496 blocks
```

What is the problem here and how can I fix my boot issue?